# How to disable sleep mode on Zebra printer i.e. ZD410

Tags: zebra-printers, thermal-printer

I am working with ZD410 printer to print labels in one of my project. When I turn on ZD410 printer, after some time printer goes to sleep mode and power button is blinking. My requirement is my printer never goes to sleep mode. Please suggest any idea. Thanks in advance. I have tried few ideas but not luck.

What I have tried is

Procedure1:

1. Install "Zebra Printer Setup Utility" mobile app in android.
2. Connect ZD410 printer to this zebra printer setup utility app.
3. Send below commands via .txt file to the connected printer:

   ```
   ! U1 setvar "power.energy_star.enable" "off"
   ! U1 setvar "power.energy_star.timeout" "0"
                  or
   ! U1 setvar "power.sleep.enable" "off"
   ! U1 setvar "power.sleep.timeout" "0"
   ```

Printer received file successfully with getting any error but printer will not return any thing and sleep mode is not disabled.

Procedure2:

1. Install "Zebra Printer Setup Utility" windows software.
2. Connect ZD410 printer to windows with USB cabel.
3. Run zebra printer setup utility software and select connected printer.
4. Send below commands to the connected printer:

   ```
   ! U1 setvar "power.energy_star.enable" "off"
   ! U1 setvar "power.energy_star.timeout" "0"
                  or
   ! U1 setvar "power.sleep.enable" "off"
   ! U1 setvar "power.sleep.timeout" "0"
   ```

Printer will not return any thing and sleep mode is not disabled.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a setvar command, the printer never return anything; if the command is correct, the settings is simply changed.
What you can do to check if the setting has actually been changed, is to use the same commmand but with a getvar instructions.

I.E.

! U1 getvar "power.energy_star.enable"

will show "on" or "off" according to the current status of this setting.
What is important to know, with the SGD commands, is that you must always add a carriage return after the last line, otherwise the command will not be processed by the printer, so in your case you should send

! U1 setvar "power.energy_star.enable" "off"

In addition, this command is correct, but some of the oldest firmware doesn't allow you to turn off the sleep mode so to check this, you can get the [allcv report](https://www.thezcorner.com/printers/languages/set-get-do-sgd/printers-sgd-commands-allcv) and check what option you have beside "power.energy_star.enable": if you see nothing, you must first upgrade the firmware because the latest one allows you to turn the sleep mode off using the command you're trying to use.

Comment: Thank you for your solutions. my existing firmware is not accepting the printer. after updating my printer firmware to latest version i.e. ..23z v, sleep mode disable commands give expected results.